# Implementing pagination on article in strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

```
async function find(ctx) {
    return await strapi.services.article.find(ctx.query)
}
```

This is my controller

```
resolver: async (obj, options, ctx) => {
    const result = await strapi.query('active').model.find({ article_id: obj.id}); 
    return result.length > 0;
}
```

This is my resolver

I have this on my strapi backend and I am trying to figure out how to do pagination. Because there are so many ways to go about it and it's not documented very well, I am not sure what we can do. Is this using Mongoose and also, how do you send the data from the controller to the resolver exactly?

```
resolver: async (obj, options, ctx) => {
    const result = await strapi.query('active').model.find({ article_id: obj.id}).limit(obj.limit).offset(obj.offset); 
    return result.length > 0;
}
```

Is it possible to do this since I am assuming it is mongoose that's being used? If not, how can we change the resolver to paginate the articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for strapi v3, you can use something like this:

```
const result = await strapi.query("model").find({
      id: id,
      _start: page > 0 ? (page - 1) * pageSize : 0,
      _limit: pageSize,
      _sort: "created_at:desc",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the Query Engine API that has build in pagination:

```
strapi.db.query('api::article.article').findMany({
  offset: 15, 
  limit: 10,
});
```

docs: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine/order-pagination.html#pagination.

Comment: Is there something for v3? I haven't found anything for v3. I am getting an error saying findMany is not a function in v3.